# Problema al capturar un valor el cual viene por POST

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

let selectCards =$('#cards');  
let idSelectCards = selectCards[0].id;

let selectEstados =  $('#estados');
let idSelectEstados = selectEstados[0].id;

let selectDistritos = $('#distritos');
let idSelectDistritos = selectDistritos[0].id;

let selectProvincias = $('#provincias');
let idSelectProvincias = selectProvincias[0].id

let selectCategoria = $('#categoria');
let idSelectCategoria = selectCategoria[0].id;



function cargarOpciones (select, idSelect, valorCard, valorEstados){

 $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: 'cargar_estados.php',
        data:{
                id:idSelect,
                valorCard:valorCard,
                valorEdo:valorEstados // No veo por que no recibo
            },
        dataType:'json'
    })
    .done(function(lista_rep1){
      
        select.empty();
        select.append('<option selected disabled value="0">Seleccione...</option>');
        for (var i = 0; i < lista_rep1.length; i++) {
            select.append('<option value="'+lista_rep1[i][idSelect]+'">'+lista_rep1[i][idSelect]+'</option>');
        };
    })
    .fail(function(){
        alert('error al cargar las listas');
    });
}

cargarOpciones(selectCards, idSelectCards);
//cargarOpciones(selectEstados, idSelectEstados)
//cargarOpciones(selectEstados)

$('#cards').change(function(event) {
        var valor = $('#cards').val();
        $('#estados').empty();
        
        cargarOpciones(selectEstados, idSelectEstados, valor);
       
    });

$('#estados').change(function(event) {
        var valorEstados = $('#estados').val();
        $('#distritos').empty();
    console.log( "el valor es :"+valorEstados);
        cargarOpciones(selectDistritos, idSelectDistritos, valorEstados);
       
    });
});
```

```html
<?php

    $columna = (empty($_POST['id'])) ?      NULL : $_POST['id'];   
    $valorCard = $_POST['valorCard'];   
    $valorEstados = $_POST['valorEdo'];
  
        require_once 'conexion.php';  
        $json=getData($columna,$valorCard,$valorEstados);

    header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
    echo json_encode($json);

function getData($columna, $valorCard, $valorEstados){
    switch ($columna){
        case 'cards':
            $con = getCon();
            $query = "SELECT
                        commerce_brand cards
                    FROM
                        commerc
                    GROUP BY
                        commerce_brand";
            $result = $con->query($query);

            while ($datos = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $row[]=$datos;
            }
                //print_r($row[1]);
            return $row;
        break;

        case 'estados':
            $con = getCon();
            $query="SELECT
                      commerce_region estados
                    FROM
                      commerc
                    WHERE
                      commerce_brand = '$valorCard'
                    GROUP BY
                      commerce_region";
            $result = $con->query($query);
            while ($datos = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $row[]=$datos;
                }
                //print_r($row);
                return $row;

            break;

            case 'distritos':
                $con = getCon();
                $query="SELECT
                            commerce_district as distritos
                        FROM 
                            commerc
                        WHERE 
                           commerce_brand = '$valorCard' and commerce_region ='$valorEstados'
                        group by  
                            commerce_district";
                $result = $con->query($query);
                while ($datos = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                        $row[]=$datos;
                    }
                    //print_r($valorEstados."valor");
                    return $row;

            break;

            case 'provincias':
                $con = getCon();
                $query="SELECT
                            commerce_province as provincias
                        FROM
                            commerc
                        WHERE
                            commerce_province = '$valorCard'
                        GROUP BY
                            commerce_province";
                $result = $con->query($query);
                while ($datos = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                        $row[]=$datos;
                    }
                    //var_dump($row);
                    return $row;
            break;

            default:
                $probando = array ("error"=>"La columna $columna no está admitida");
            return $probando;
        }
    }

?>
```

**no logro recibir el valor valorEdo:valorEstados en el archivo .php cuando voy hacer uso de  $valorEstados = $_POST['valorEdo']; que es donde intento capturar dicho valor me dice que esta null no veo cual es el error o que estoy haciendo mal **

Comment: Tu funcion `cargarOpciones` recibe 4 parametros, pero en ninguna de las dos llamadas que tienes mandas 4.

Comment: Gracias tu comentario me ayudo ahora tengo otro problema en el archivo js tengo una variable llamada valor pero esta dentro de una funcion y cuando trato de usarla dentro de otra funcion que es la siguiente me dice que esa variable esta undefined que puede hacer para obtener el valor de esa variable o que debo hacer para usarla en la otra funcion ?

Comment: Puedes hacerla una variable global sacandola de la funcion.  Puedes definirla donde defines las otras variables con `let` al principio de tu codigo.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda. Saludos